# Any configuration for type of style section loaded in head tag?

Tags: magento2, configuration, css, head

Is there any configuration that makes style section loaded like this in head tag:

```
<style data-href="http://www.website.com/pub/static/frontend/Mytheme/mytheme/fr_FR/mage/calendar.css" media="all"> ....</style>
```

Instead of like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="www.website.com/pub/static/frontend/Mytheme/mytheme/fr_FR/mage/calendar.css" />
```

In fact, I want it to be a link tag like by default, but maybe a configuration makes it changed to inline style tag, and I can not find what configuration has been changed.

Comment: Did you miss something in your question ?

Comment: Solved, it was a custom js file that makes it happen, it was not configuration

Answer (score 0):

Yes, possiable, Just go to `Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer`

at function  getAssetTemplate()

```
protected function getAssetTemplate($contentType, $attributes)
{
    switch ($contentType) {
        case 'js':
            $groupTemplate = '<script ' . $attributes . ' src="%s"></script>' . "\n";
            break;

        case 'css':
        default:
            $groupTemplate = '<link ' . $attributes . ' href="%s" />' . "\n";
            break;
    }
    return $groupTemplate;
}
```

**You need to modify*** from `link to **`style`**